# Display by color groups of units in sf map

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, r-sf

I have technical question for you :

I have a shapfile of few cities in a district

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(sf)

    read_sf("cities.shp")  %>% 
      ggplot() +  geom_sf() + theme_bw()
```

My shp look like that :

```
   Code  Name   Long Lat    Groups
   <chr> <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl> <dbl>
 1 34001 ABEI…   724751. 6262333.     9
 2 34002 ADIS…   734961. 6270688.    10
 3 34003 AGDE    739245. 6245728.     7
 4 34004 AGEL    688135. 6249905.     4
 5 34005 AGON…   758530. 6311345.    20
 6 34006 AIGNE   683215. 6247000.     4
 7 34007 AIGU…   685638. 6249976.     4
 8 34008 LES …   705573. 6274482.     6
 9 34009 ALIG…   727555. 6263258.     9
10 34010 ANIA…   747789. 6287511.    18
```

I would like to have a map with cities, but also with city grouping (variable Groups). So my cities of the same group would be surrounded by a line (red for example) of their groupings. I would like to display my cities AND display my groups. I would also like to know if it is possible to color the groups with a transparency effect so that we can see the boundaries of the communes below.

Thank you

Comment: no idea what you want. Please revise your question.

Comment: Have you taken a look at the `geom_mark_*()` family of geoms in the ggforce package?

Comment: I do not know if this fits my expectations since the boundaries of my groups are the outer borders of city gatherings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it was simple ...

Like ohter `geom_x` code we can use arg `fill =`

```
 (test <- read_sf("map.shp") %>% mutate(Groups = as.factor(Groups)) %>% 
        mutate(Groups = factor(Groups, levels = c(paste0(1:23)))) %>%
      ggplot() +  geom_sf(aes(fill = Groups)) + theme_bw() )
```

That all, Thx !

Comment: If anyone knows how to increase only the size of the outlines of my groups, I'm interested!

Thank you